# How do you make a line go to and past mouse position?

Tags: python

I want to draw a line using pygame.draw.line(), and make that line go from any coordinates, through the mouse position, and onward. I know how to make a line from any coordinates go to the mouses position and stop there, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Why do you not know the end co-ordinates?

Comment: You have two points on the line.  From this, you can calculate any desired endpoint, given one of the coordinates.  Show your coding attempt and the problem you have with that.

Comment: @marienbad Because I want the line to go through the mouse position

Comment: You surely know how far you want it to go, though?

Comment: @marienbad just outside of the screen, how do I do it?

Comment: How is it that you don't know either coordinate of the endpoint?  Do you have some sort of a quantum problem, or an infinite output realm?

Comment: If you know that the endpoint is "just outside of the screen", then you have a way to determine one coordinate of an endpoint.  From that, you compute the other.

Comment: @Prune I don't have an endpoint, I just know I want it to go from one place, through the mouse and out of the screen in a straight line

Comment: @Prune alright but how?

Comment: I did not say that you have an endpoint: I said that you have sufficient information to determine one coordinate of that endpoint.  Work with pencil & paper; solve the problem there, and code what you determine.

Comment: @Prune How would I do this when the mouse can be anywhere on the screen?

Comment: You said you know how to make a line from any coordinate go to the mouse's position and stop there. You must have the mouse's coordinate for that. Through 2 points passes a single line. From there you can compute your desired endpoint. Basically a math problem...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing line with infinity length in the direction of cursor in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47481967/6045800)

Comment: Perfect! I'm really happy to hear. Can you please mark the question as duplicate then?

Answer (score 0):

`mpos` is the mouse position (mouse.pos) and x and y the start co-ords. `width` is the width of the surface. Switch it around to draw in other directions:

```
dx = abs(self.mpos[0] - x)
dy = abs(self.mpos[1] - y)

x_dist = width - self.mpos[0]
y_dist = height - self.mpos[1]
new_x = self.mpos[0]
new_y = self.mpos[0]

while x_dist < width:
    new_x += dx
    new_y += dy
    x_dist += dx
    
pygame.draw.line(self, white, (x,y), (new_x, new_y), 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You already have two points on the line: your start point, and the mouse position.  Derive the equation of that line.

Now, look at the two points, determining your direction.  Let's work with horizontal: what is the x-coordinate of the screen edge in the direction you will draw this line?  Call that `x_limit`.  Plug that value into your linear equation (call it `f`) to get `y_limit = f(x_limit)`.

Now you have a simple check: is the point `(x_limit, y_limit)` on the edge of the screen?  If not, then your `y` value runs off the screen before the `x` value does.  In that case, set `y_limit` to the edge in the `y` direction.  Use this `y_limit` value to compute a new `x_limit`.  This is guaranteed to give you a point on the edge -- your desired endpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have no idea how I would derive in python but maybe that's because I'm tired, I'll try your solution tomorrow and let you know if it worked. Thanks again

Comment: @Squarex Please see the link I provided under the question for an existing implementation you can work on for your needs

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks I will check it out